# Why thinner strings in a pair are on top position?

Tags: guitar

When I play twelve string guitar, it bothers me that when I play the bass strings too gently, sometimes only the thinner string of the pair gets played, thus without the desired bass sound.

I wonder why it is like that, and mostly I woul like to know if there is a problem if I swap them.

Comment: being able to swap them depends on your instrument, specifically the nut. Generally the nut is slotted for the string gauges, so switching positions would require widening the thin string's slot to allow the new thicker string.  If you have a zero fret or other nut system you may not need to alter it, so answer depends.

Answer (score 4):

When the pick touches the thicker string first, the likelihood that it passes by the second string entirely is higher.  On the backstroke, the pick is usually tilted stronger so that this is less likely to happen.

According to the [Wikipedia article on twelve-string guitars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve-string_guitar), Rickenbacker's electric guitars have their courses wired reversely but most other makers do it with the higher note in upper position.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.